# Measuring web performance metrices in TypeScript front end program

Tags: typescript, performance-testing, w3c

My front end is written in Angular9, TypeScript.

I am interested to annotate my app with different page load time performance metrics (both browser timing as well as DOM handling) as suggested by W3 working group [W3 performance working group](https://www.w3.org/webperf/).

How can I start importing the Performance object in my TypeScript app such that I can start monitoring the different performance metrics as mentioned [here](https://web.dev/user-centric-performance-metrics/#important-metrics-to-measure).

Thanks,
Pradip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Performance APIs are provided by the browsers, so if you are looking to use them directly, you do not need to import anything. I've copied the example on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigationTiming/domInteractive):

```
function print_nav_timing_data() {
  // Use getEntriesByType() to just get the "navigation" events
  var perfEntries = performance.getEntriesByType("navigation");

  for (var i=0; i < perfEntries.length; i++) {
    console.log("= Navigation entry[" + i + "]");
    var p = perfEntries[i];
    // dom Properties
    console.log("DOM content loaded = " + (p.domContentLoadedEventEnd - p.domContentLoadedEventStart));
    console.log("DOM complete = " + p.domComplete);
    console.log("DOM interactive = " + p.domInteractive);
 
    // document load and unload time
    console.log("document load = " + (p.loadEventEnd - p.loadEventStart));
    console.log("document unload = " + (p.unloadEventEnd - p.unloadEventStart));
    
    // other properties
    console.log("type = " + p.type);
    console.log("redirectCount = " + p.redirectCount);
  }
}
```

If you are just interested in measuring those specific metrics, however, you could just use the web-vitals project they have provided [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/web-vitals). The usage looks like this:

```
import {getFCP} from 'web-vitals';

// Measure and log the current FCP value,
// any time it's ready to be reported.
getFCP(console.log);
```

Since the source is available, you can see how they use the APIs as well.

Comment: Thanks. By accessing the performance object, can I also get the https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_network related information as well?

Comment: I can't say for sure it's a 1:1 match, but yes should be able to get resource information; there is a "resource" type which has timings and size.